# MySQL select taking ages

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following select query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename
WHERE (c1 = 'text1' AND (c2 = 'text2' OR c3 = 'text2' OR c4 LIKE 'text2%'))
ORDER BY c5 DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

This table has more than 27 million rows in it, but there is an index for `c1`, `c2`, `c3` and `c4`.

The problem is this query takes more then 20 minutes to execute. Any ideas how to make this faster?

I took out the ORDER BY, and it finished in 34 seconds - but how to do this with the ORDER BY in. (`c5` Is a `DATETIME` column the rest are `VARCHAR(80)`)

Comment: what does `explain` says for the query ?

Comment: Can you add the result of EXPLAIN statement

Comment: What if the index was a compound index on (c1,c4)

Comment: Dow you have one compound index on C1, C2, C3 and C4 or are they 4 separete indexes?

Comment: The Indexes are separate - I could never find any definitive answer on whats better: compound or separate?

Comment: How can `c4` be `DATETIME` and be queried for `LIKE 'text2%'`? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: My Bad, c4 should be c5... ill edit it now

Comment: So is C5 a TEXT column by any chance? If so you might want to check which filesort algorithm is used there

Answer (score 1):

If the query works fast without the `order by`, then use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM mytablename
      WHERE (c1 = 'text1' AND (c2 = 'text2' OR c3 = 'text2' OR c4 LIKE 'text2%'))
     ) t
ORDER BY c5 DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

There is a big note about performance.  When you remove the `order by`, you are fetching the first 25 rows encountered.  With the `order by` (in either query), you need to fetch the entire matching result set.  That can take much longer, regardless of which method you use.

So, to be comparable, you need to run the query without the `order by` *and* without the `limit`.  How long does that take?

Comment: Wooohoo! 14 seconds :)

Comment: I have changed c4 to c5, to make it true. (I could not update yours)

Comment: @ConraddeWet I reckon if you combine this subquery with my answer and put an index on the `datetime` (if it's not there already) you can bring it down even more :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, Please try and lemme know if this works :

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename
WHERE (c1 = 'text1' AND (c2 = 'text2' OR c3 = 'text2' OR c4 LIKE 'text2%'))
and c4 = (SELECT MIN(c4) from mytablename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY which can diminish the usefulness of the index :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

By removing the order by statement you are fetching the first 25 results, so that might not be a good benchmark.

Explain statement would help but looks like you need a compound index containing everything you use.

Answer (score 0):

Your query has to select all 27 million rows and check for the `WHERE`, then order it, and then only give you the first 25 rows. But you really do want the top 25 most recent items probably. My experience is that `OR` and `LIKE` tend to slow things down, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytablename
WHERE c1 = 'text1' AND 'text2' IN (c2, c3, LEFT(c4, 5))
ORDER BY c5 DESC
LIMIT 0, 25;
```

***edit:*** since you changed the mistake of `c4/c5`, does `c5` have an index? Helps with sorting.

If that's still too slow, look into partitioning, do you really wanna query the items from 10 years ago? Maybe put those in a different partition.

Comment: Yes, all columns have separate index (not compound).